# Can Apache be integrated with 3rd party cookie session authentication/authorization?

Tags: apache-2.2, configuration, authentication, authorization, middleware

I'd like to configure Apache to serve files directly from the file system but authenticate/authorize users.  How can Apache be configured so it calls my auth middleware?

Basically:

1) Redirect to login if user is not authenticated.  Check session cookie against database otherwise.

2) Allow access to certain files based on who the user is (authorization).

Comment: Any more details? What authentication does your current system use?

Answer (score 5):

Try a Google search for "apache single signon" or "apache sso".  In particular, look at:

- [mod_auth_tkt](http://www.openfusion.com.au/labs/mod_auth_tkt/)
- [mod_auth_pubtkt](https://neon1.net/mod_auth_pubtkt/)
- [Shibboleth](http://shibboleth.internet2.edu/)
- [Pubcookie](http://www.pubcookie.org/)
- [Cosign](http://cosign.sourceforge.net/)

All of these implement almost exactly the mechanism you've described.